# Can I restrict a specific user to using only localhost?

Tags: linux, networking

I have several NodeJS servers that are access through an Nginx server. Nginx relays to the NodeJS servers through localhost. At this point I am doing all the work, so I know I can do what needs to be done, but in the future I'd like the users to run their own servers.

What I need to do is restrict any given non-root user to having access ONLY to localhost. Can I do this?

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Comment: Sorry - yes, Ubuntu 16.x.

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the traffic for your users using *iptables owner module* allowing only loopback interface:

```
# accept incoming packets to loopback device
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid $USER -o lo -j ACCEPT
# drop everything else
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid $USER -j DROP
```

With above rules, the user can still create a process listening in non-restricted ports, even if it cannot reply to any messages it receives. You can also write the rules as a white list for whole system: first accept all good traffic and drop everything else.

For filtering incoming traffic, owner module cannot be used (see the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html)). You can configure input chain to allow *established* traffic and drop other incoming traffic not explcitly allowed.

```
# change default action to drop
iptables -P INPUT DROP
# allow established connections (replies)
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If you are running services which listen to network port(s), you need to add respective rules to allow them to receive traffic.